# iOS: AVPlayer play won't play sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

So I have an app built with a player that plays a video, I have a [player pause] and [player play] in the didBecomeActive and willResignActive methods. Most of the time works fine, but when I open the app, and press the home button and repeat again that process, around the 8th time the video will not play even though I see the play method getting called.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: share some code (your delegates and methods) so people can help you

Answer (score 1):

The app can be in several states that are not foreground.  Before playing, check to see if you still have a `player`, that it still has a `player.currentItem`, and if it's status is `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay`.

If any of those conditions are not met, then the player and the item must be reinitialized using the code that you used to create it in the first place.

This is a good candidate for a lazy initializer for your `player` property.

Comment: it looks that the problem is within the last remaining 1 second of video play - if I press the Home button then and open the app again - I notice that the player has a currentItem, its rate is set as 1.0 and is ReadyToPlay yet the Play method does nothing. As a workaround I've added a code to destroy the player item and build it again if the user presses the home button within the last second of the video :(

Comment: what could be happening is that the player state is changing in a race with the app changing active state.  do you implement app will resign active?  https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622950-applicationwillresignactive  you should, pausing or stopping the playback.

Comment: yes, in the Resign State I pause the player and checked that the state is ReadyToPlay.